# Help asking about the spirit and the body (on topic?)

Tags: discussion, scope

Is this question on topic? If so, what are some appropriate tags?

---

The phrasing of [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/24560/do-angels-possess-1-a-body-soul-and-spirit-2-a-soul-and-spirit-or-3-just-a) on Christianity.SE has me thinking.

According to the Bible, *is* man spirit and flesh, or does man *have* a spirit and a body of flesh?

Consider these verses from the OT:

> Genesis 2:7 Then the LORD God formed man of dust from the ground, and breathed into his nostrils the breath of life; and man **became a living being**.
>
> Psalm 42:2 **My soul** thirsts for God, for the living God;
> When shall I come and appear before God?

And these from the NT:

> 1 Corinthians 15:45 So also it is written, “The first man, Adam, became a living soul.” The last Adam **became a life-giving spirit.**
>
> Corinthians 1:23 But I call God as witness to **my soul**, that to spare you I did not come again to Corinth.

Are these differences significant? Are the notions of *being* a soul and *having* a soul conflated in the Bible?

Comment: I'm going to say your question *being revised to ask the meaning of the text* is a perfect fit for BHSE. If you are examining various theological viewpoints, then your question is about theology and not about understanding the text, consequently it is "Off-Topic". If your question is about understanding the text, then challenging various theological viewpoints as they relate to the text, then it is entirely "On-Topic" and part of the reason why we're here. "Understanding the Text" is the critical piece, our theology/worldviews are formed from that.

Answer (score 5):

I concur with the [existing answer](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3177/2215) that this question would be "off-topic" as posed.

I also think there are at least two "on-topic" questions lurking in it, and to let them out it would mean:

- (much!) tighter focus; and
- restricting the "corpus".

Essentially the question as it stands is about a the "doctrine of man" [*sic*] or "biblical anthropology" (in this technical sense), perhaps the sort of thing Nancey Murphy, *[Bodies and Souls, or Spirited Bodies?](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-RxdcpDZfxIC&printsec=frontcover)* (Cambridge University Press, 2006) is interested in.

One attempt to get at this from the perspective of (Christian) biblical theology is provided by Brevard Childs, *[Biblical Theology of the Old and New Testaments: Theological Reflection on the Christian Bible](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=0rA-9UPxCZMC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA566#v=onepage&q&f=false)* (Fortress, 1993), ch. VII, "Humanity Old and New".

My suggestion would be to isolate texts from the Old Testament and New Testament, and ask discrete questions about the meaning of those individual texts -- after checking out whether they have been asked about before, of course! There are, for example, two questions already (at least) about Genesis 2:7

- [God's breath in Genesis 2:7](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/8162/2215)
- [Is “breath of life” in Genesis 2:7 is the same as spirit?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/2739/2215)

In this way you could patiently build up the *biblical* resources from which you could then develop the more synthetic sort of account that Hermeneutics.SE itself will not provide.

Answer (score 3):

It's off topic in my view because it essentially "starts from an idea" rather than "starts from a text".

Basically, it's clear from the post the you are interested in the question "is man spirit and flesh, or does man have a spirit and a body of flesh?" and are on a quest to find whether this is consistent with scripture, rather than having arrived at the question while looking at the text.

Comment: Thank you. I'm more interested in how the reading of those linguistic notions in the Bible evolved independent of or in conjunction with extra-biblical philosophies, and whether or not these notions are distinct or conflated in the reading or if they are significantly expressed in the diction.

Comment: So some kind of 'history of interpretation'? I can see that might possibly be on-topic if it focused on a single verse, but not if it focuses on the ideas.